# Are there any trade-offs between react-native-permissions and expo-permission?

Tags: react-native, react-native-permissions, expo-permissions

I'm trying to select between react-native-permissions or expo-permissions for my project. They both work on iOS and Android but expo-permissions code is more concise. Other than that, are there any trade-offs between the two that I should be aware of?

I'm using bare react-native workflow without Expo.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a bare react-native workflow you should use react-native-permissions, because expo-permissions is only for expo managed workflows.

Although Expo has [react-native-unimodules](https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules) package that can give you the permissions module.

If you read the docs for [expo-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-permissions) you can see this thing in installation guide. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify I'm using bare react-native workflow. I've already have expo-permissions installed via react-native-unimodules. Are there any trade-offs between the two packages?